# Can't see the application servers menu in InteliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure Tomcat 7.0.37 server in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5. I added it as an application server, but I can't see the application servers menu.
Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between IntelliJ Ultimate and Community editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843882/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-intellij-ultimate-and-community-editions)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson it's not a duplicate, the screenshot clearly shows that he's already using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (note Spring and Web tool windows which are not available in the Community Edition).

Answer (score 1):

Application servers are configured in the [Settings (Preferences) dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-preferences-dialog.html):

[image: app servers]

This feature is [available only](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

[Application Servers tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/application-servers-tool-window.html) appears only for the web projects that are configured to use an app server:

[image: servers]

Comment: Thank for your help.
I have already set up Application Servers setting in IntelliJ 2017.2.5 and is there no way to fix this issue in my version?

Comment: @IvanVolkonov make sure you have a web project, for the Maven project it should have `<packaging>war</packaging>` in `pom.xml`.